# How to hide animation in chat UITableView endscrolling in chatting?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on chat application.When I select a particular chat list it opens `ChatViewController`. All I want is screen should show directly last message in chat screen(like other chat app). I have implemented following code for that:

```
if(chatData.count>1)
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:chatData.count-1 inSection:0];
    [chatTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

But when chat screen shown it is on top for very few millisecond and it scroll to last row sudden.

I want to hide this animation or process and directly open last message. I want to hide this scrolling animation.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652233/in-ios-how-to-stop-uitableview-cell-scroll-animation-when-page-load-programatica)!

Comment: @NDoc, why did you remove Objective-C tag? Because someone might want to search for iOS questions with only Objective-C Tag.

Comment: Tag was removed by you @Mr.UB check [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39163124/revisions).

Comment: Thanks for pointing. May be I pressed wrong button. Strange my edit approved.

Comment: quick fix would be to hide the table view and setHidden = NO after scrollToRowAtIndexPath: in if() condition  and also add a else part { setHidden = NO }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this problem.Forgot to make animation = NO in this method Thank you so much everybody.......

```
  - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
  [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

  CGFloat yOffset = 0;
  if (chatTableView.contentSize.height > chatTableView.bounds.size.height) 
  {
     yOffset = chatTableView.contentSize.height - (chatTableView.bounds.size.height-10);
  }

  [chatTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, yOffset) animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the thing is that you don't need to scroll it with animation.

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

In **viewWillAppear** try below code

```
[tableView reloadData];
int lastRowNumber = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1;
NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowNumber inSection:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO]
```